# QThreads no QT Creator

Tags: c++, qt, thread, socket

criei um servidor no QT Creator, e também implementei o serviço de Threads nele. Mas quando eu faço conexão no servidor, com a aplicação "Cliente" e envio um dado, o servidor não recebe ... Ele deveria receber e imprimir o dado recebido, mas isso não está acontecendo... Vou postar o codigo do servidor aqui, se alguém souber como resolver agradeço!

OBs: Eu já fiz um teste com o cliente, enviando dado para um servidor sem o serviço de threads, e o servidor recebeu. Ou seja, o cliente está funcionando normalmente... Acredito que algo esteja errado com as threads nesse servidor.

**mythread.h**

```
#ifndef THREAD_H
#define THREAD_H

#include <QThread>
#include <QTcpSocket>
#include <QTcpServer>

class MyThread : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyThread(int ID, QObject *parent = 0);
    void run();

signals:
    void error(QTcpSocket::SocketError socketerror);

public slots:
    void readyRead();
    void disconnected();

private:
    QTcpSocket *socket;
    int socketDescriptor;

};

#endif // THREAD_H
```

**mythread.c**

```
 #include "mythread.h"

MyThread::MyThread(int ID, QObject *parent) : QThread(parent)
{
    this->socketDescriptor = ID;
}

void MyThread::run() {
    qDebug() << "Starting thread";
    socket = new QTcpSocket();

    connect(socket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(readyRead()), Qt::DirectConnection);
    connect(socket, SIGNAL(disconnected()), this, SLOT(disconnected()), Qt::DirectConnection);

    if(!socket->setSocketDescriptor(this->socketDescriptor)) {
        emit error(socket->error());
        return;
    }

    qDebug() << "Client connected";
}

void MyThread::readyRead() {
    QByteArray data = socket->readAll();
    qDebug()<< data;
    socket->write(data);
}

void MyThread::disconnected() {
    qDebug() << socketDescriptor << " Disconnected";
    socket->deleteLater();
    exit(0);
}
```

**server.c**

```
#include "server.h"

Server::Server(QObject *parent) : QTcpServer(parent)
{
}

void Server::StartServer() {

    if(!this->listen(QHostAddress::Any, 10000)) {
        qDebug() << "Could not start server";
    } else {
        qDebug() << "Listening...";
    }
}

void Server::incomingConnection(int socketDescriptor) {
    qDebug() << socketDescriptor << " Connecting...";
    MyThread *thread = new MyThread(socketDescriptor, this);
    connect(thread, SIGNAL(finished()), thread, SLOT(deleteLater()));
    thread->start();
}
```

**server.h**

```
#ifndef SERVER_H
#define SERVER_H

#include <QTcpServer>
#include <QDebug>
#include "mythread.h"


class Server : public QTcpServer
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Server(QObject *parent = 0);
    void StartServer();

signals:

public slots:

protected:
    void incomingConnection(int socketDescriptor);

};

#endif // SERVER_H
```

**main.c**

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include "server.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    Server server;
    server.StartServer();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema está no seu método `MyThread::run()`, quando ele chega ao fim a `thread` associada a ele também é finalizada ou seja não há nem tempo do seu `socket` aguardar por novas conexões.

Outro ponto importante é que na nova `thread` não existe um `event loop` para processar os eventos dos `QObjects` criados nela, isso inclui seu `socket`.

Conclusão, além de ser destruído no mesmo instante que foi criado, após o método e a `thread` serem encerrados, seu `socket` também está incapaz de processar `signals`.

Ao final de `MyThread::run()` adicione:

```
this->exec();
```

Utilizando `QThread::exec()` você **impede** que `MyThread::run()` retorne, mantendo a `thread` ativa, e **permite** que os eventos dos `QObjects` criados dentro dela possam ser processados.

Você pode ler mais em [QThread](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html).

Comment: Resolveu :D, obrigado!!!